# Gauss hyper geometric function

Tags: r

I want to calculate the value of Gauss hyper geometric function $2F2 (a_1, a_2; b_1,b_2; z)$ in R, where z is a real number. I am unable to find a package for this. Most of packages discuss on $2F1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a1 = 1
a2 = 2
b1 = 3
b2 = 4
z = -5

library(hypergeo)
genhypergeo(c(a1,a2), c(b1,b2), z)
# 0.5345019

library(HypergeoMat)
hypergeomPFQ(m=50, a = c(a1,a2), b = c(b1,b2), x = z)
# 0.5345019
```